# Can I permently connect the resistant of a coffee machine

Tags: switches, heat, repair, thermostat

I have a simple coffee machine that has a little "controller" that control the ON/OFF of the heater.
Suddenly, the machine stop heating the water (and the recipient). I have open the base and test with a continuity tester the thermostat and the heater. The two parts pass the test.

I thought that the problem is from the electronic part.

The question is: Can I connect the thermostat-heater directly to power and adding a switch on the AC cable?

Comment: You can but if you have fire insurance and a fire, it may be voided after inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed my coffee maker this morning with exactly the same symptoms.

The thick heater was clamped to the baseplate and had a large thermostat switch to automate the heater temp. Both heater and thermostat were ok. But in the middle just below the baseplate ( or above viewed from bottom) were two thermal fuses (192'C) in series. One was open and all were in series with heater. Other was good but I decided to replace both so that if one failed short instead of open and second failed the same along with thermostat, a fire would not occur. thus triple protection with dual thermal fuses and one thermostat.

Cost $2.50 each.  Crimp on tight both sides with pliers so steel sleeve prevents wire movement with a twist or pull.

[image]

SAYAL's in Toronto had everything I needed, so it was just a small detour from dropping off my wife at the subway.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to locate these fuses and test it.

Answer (score 2):

In series with the mains supply, the thermostat and the heating element there is mostprobably also a thermal fuse. It is soldered in place and opens permanently if the temperature of the coffee machine has been to hot. This is done to prevent damage or even fire to your house. If that is the case the fuse must be replaced with one of the same specifications.

A warning again. Dont short circuit the fuse because of the increased risk of fire hazard and be carefull since you are working with a mains supplied appliance.